# How to fix Such error " No Mapping exists from object type anystore.bLL.loginBLL to a known managed provider native type ". Well i checked so manytime

Tags: c#

```
class loginDAL
{
    //Static String to connect database
    static string myconnstrng = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstrng"].ConnectionString;
    public bool LoginCheck(loginBLL l)
    {
        //Create a boolean variable and set its value to false and return it
        bool isSuccess = false;

        //Connecting to DataBase
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstrng);
        try
        {
            //SQL Query to check login
            string sql = "SELECT * From tbl_users WHERE username=@username AND password=@password AND user_type=@user_type";
            //Creating Sql Command to pass value 
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", l);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", l);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_type", l);

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            //Checking the rows in DataTable
            if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                //Login Successful
                isSuccess = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //Login Failed
                isSuccess = false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return isSuccess;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `loginBLL`?

Comment: You are passing in the entire `l` object into the parameter instead of the value. Try `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", l.Username);` for example.

Comment: Also read https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: And don't store passwords in the database. Use salted hashes instead.

Comment: Thank You So much @ DavidG, Now it works.